# How to set a default value of a property on every object that implements an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have a property called Color on my IVehicle interface. If I want every vehicle that implements that interface to have a default color of "Red" how could I achieve this? Do I need another level here?

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    string Color { get; set; }

    void Go();        
    void Stop();
}

public class Bmw : IVehicle
{

    #region IVehicle Members

    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Go()
    {

    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I think you should look at an abstract class, which is better suited for these types of things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I want every vehicle that inherits from that interface to have a default color of "Red" how could I achieve this?

This would really be an implementation detail, so it's not part of the interface.  The interface can't dictate how a class implements it - only what members must be implemented.

If you want this type of control, you might want to use an `abstract class` instead of an interface.  A `Vehicle` base class could setup the default implementation using `Colors.Red`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't "*inherit*" from an interface, you "*implement*" it. A default color would be part of the implementation. So yes you need "another level" It could be an abastract or concrete class that your child classes inherit from.

Note: You can implement many interfaces but only inherit from one class.

Comment: Fixed it thanks. I always get that wording mixed up. At some point it will stick.

Answer (score 0):

Provided there isn't a specific reason your using an interface over an abstract class (such as the things implementing it already having a base class), then an abstract class is the way to go. You also need to make sure to declare the property as virtual, otherwise it won't be able to be overriden by the inheriting classes.